# How to store resources on android so that they can be opened with fopen

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am programming a game in C++ that I intend to have running on both PC and Android. I have a few images and text files that I am using in my game. Where can I put these files so that they can be opened with `ifstream` or `fopen`? I feel inclined to mention that I have already experimented with storing them in the assets folder and can load them using the NDK AssetManager. My main problem with the assets folder is that `ifstream` can't actually open files stored there due to the fact that they're compressed or something of that nature. For the most part, that would be okay, but I have some libraries that are essential and they only accept the path to the file being used. Additionally, it would be nice to have (almost) the same code being used to load files on PC and android.

T.L.D.R.: Where can I put the resources for my game so that they can be opened with `ifstream`? I read somewhere that I could use external storage or something of that sort, but I would prefer another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I put these files so that they can be opened with ifstream or fopen?

You would need to package them in your app (e.g., `assets/`), then copy them to files on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `getFilesDir()`). Nothing that gets packaged with your app winds up as ordinary files that can be used with `fopen()` and kin otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems like the most promising thing. I will mark your answer as accepted, but I have a few small things I'm wondering about. 1.) Is this the only way to put assets in the internal storage? Is there no place in android studio where I can put my assets and they will get automatically put in internal storage when the app is run? And 2.) If this is the only way, do the assets have to be copied into the internal storage every time the app runs, or just upon installation?

Comment: @AnonymousPerson: "Is there no place in android studio where I can put my assets and they will get automatically put in internal storage when the app is run?" -- correct. "do the assets have to be copied into the internal storage every time the app runs, or just upon installation?" -- not every time the app runs. If the file exists, leave it; if not, copy it from assets. The primary time the copy will be done is on the first run after installation, but it can also occur if the user clears your app's data via Settings.

Comment: Okay then, that's all of my questions. Thank you very much! I have managed to get it to work, and I am very satisfied with it.